# Python - How to find a correlation between two vectors?

Tags: python, algorithm, math, list-comprehension

Given two vectors *X* and *Y*, I have to find their correlation, i.e. their linear dependence/independence.  Both vectors have equal dimension.  The result should be a floating point number from [-1.0 .. 1.0].

Example:

```
X=[-1, 2,    0]
Y=[ 4, 2, -0.3]
```

Find *y = cor(X,Y)* such that *y* belongs to *[-1.0 .. 1.0]*.

It should be a simple construction involving a list-comprehension. No external library is allowed.

UPDATE: ok, if the dot product is enough, then here is my solution:

```
nX = 1/(sum([x*x for x in X]) ** 0.5)
nY = 1/(sum([y*y for y in Y]) ** 0.5)
cor = sum([(x*nX)*(y*nY)  for x,y in zip(X,Y) ])
```

right?

Comment: Is this homework?

Comment: How do you define correlation?

Comment: @Daniel: <math>\rho_{X,Y}=\mathrm{corr}(X,Y)={\mathrm{cov}(X,Y) \over \sigma_X \sigma_Y} ={E[(X-\mu_X)(Y-\mu_Y)] \over \sigma_X\sigma_Y},</math>

Comment: Your formula is not from the linear algebra domain, but from statistics. Your "vectors" are "samples" of "random variables"

Comment: @belisarius: it doesn't matter. there must be a measure of the linear dependence between two vectors

Comment: Two vectors are l.d. if and only if one is multiple of the other.

Comment: @belisarius: yes, but I am looking for a measure of their RELATIVE LINEAR DEPENDENCE, e.g. 1 and -1 if they are absolutely dependent, 0 if independent.

Comment: @psihodelia: actually your formula is what you are going to implement to calculate correlation. So what's the problem?

Comment: @JamesKolpack does it matter?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sounds like a [dot product](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dot_product) to me.

Solve the equation for the cosine of the angle between the two vectors, which is always in the range [-1, 1], and you'll have what you want.

It's equal to the dot product divided by the magnitudes of two vectors.

Comment: Doesn't the dot product range rather more widely in its possible values than [-1,1]? :-)

Comment: @Brandon: for normalized vectors it is always on [-1..1]

Comment: Not if you normalize it properly.  You're really talking about the cosine of the angle between the two, which is always [-1, 1].  Solve the dot product for the cosine and you'll have what you want.

Answer (score 4):

Since range is supposed to be `[-1, 1]` I think that the [Pearson Correlation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pearson_product-moment_correlation_coefficient) can be ok for your purposes.

Also dot-product would work but you'll have to normalize vectors before calculating it and you can have a -1,1 range just if you have also negative values.. otherwise you would have 0,1

Answer (score 2):

Don't assume because a formula is algebraically correct that its direct implementation in code will work.  There can be numerical problems with some definitions of correlation.

See [How to calculate correlation accurately](http://www.johndcook.com/blog/2008/11/05/how-to-calculate-pearson-correlation-accurately/)